# The different twins

Tags: mathematics, word, lateral-thinking, weighing

[image]

The seesaw is filled with nine pairs of identical twins. *All* the kids weigh the same (e.g., they all weigh 100, but the actual numbers are irrelevant),
except for one set of twins. They are still identical twins, so they weigh the same as *each other*, but not the same as the other 16 kids (e.g., these two children each weigh 101, but, again, the actual numbers are irrelevant).
If (exactly) four kids on one side switch positions with four other kids on the other side to balance the seesaw, which is the odd pair?

Comment: So you're saying there is one *pair* of twins that weighs a different amount, and the rest weigh the same?

Comment: Yes 1 twin. 2 kids with same weight but unlike the rest causing the tilt

Comment: There are a bunch of E's, for example, are those considered one 'twin' even though they are sextuplets? When you say 4 pairs of kids swap, is that supposed to be a minimum, or just a descriptor?

Comment: Every kid has an identical twin. Swap can be between any 2 kids for 4 times, but lets do it one time.

Comment: Just to fully clarify.  Everyone always weighs the same as their twin, and everyone on the seesaw is a twin of someone else on the seesaw.  In addition to weighing the same as their twin, everyone here actually has the same weight as everyone else, except for one pair that weigh differently (but still the same as each other)?  Or is it just that every person with the same letter has the same weight as every other person with that letter (a less narrow constraint)?

Comment: only 2 same letter weighs x , the others weighs 1..x not equal 1

Comment: Have you taken into account the position on the seesaw beam? A kid that's 20kg heavier than the rest will have more effect on the outermost position of the seesaw than one that's at the innermost position.

Comment: @IanMacDonald:  Yes, that is critical to the puzzle.  (Note that my answer, which includes an explanation, has been accepted.)

Comment: Imagine all kids weigh the same. Placing the 20kg weight on any positions both sides will tilt the seesaw if not at same distance to the fulcrum. But balance if they are on the same distance no matter how far from the fulcrum.

Comment: Wish I could ^vote twice, after seeing the solution, once for each side of this clever puzzle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "odd" pair is

> the **O** twins.

The way to balance the seesaw

> is to change
>
> ```
> ttl+eoevnn . wweove+lee
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> tWO+eLevEn = TweLve+ONe
> ```
>
> (using capital letters to show the four and four that switched). 
> This cleverly "balances" the seesaw because it spells
> `TWO+ELEVEN = TWELVE+ONE`, i.e., 2+11=12+1. 
> After this switch, the **O** twins are both third from the end,
> so the seesaw balances even though they don't weigh the same as the others. 
> That is the only letter that is *moved into* a symmetric configuration.

Comment: I expected that somebody else would get it in the 10 minutes it took me to type the explanation.

Comment: @Peregine Rook-  That is the Odd Twin. I expected it to be answered at least an hour and you are typing slow. Nice work.

Comment: What makes `WWO+eLevnn ^ TTeLve+Oee` unbalanced?

Comment: @IanMacDonald: It's lateral thinking wordplay.  WWO+eLevnn ^ TTeLve+Oee is gibberish; my solution *balances* the seesaw in a wordplay way.

Comment: Great solution, with built-in double check, makes the puzzle look all the better too

Comment: @IanMacDonald finding two+eleven = twelve+one is balanced reveals the twins that are different. The worldplay shows us which twins are wrong.